iOS/iPadOS change entries in "Open with" list
I am using iOS 18 and iPadOS 17.
When I click on a file in an app, I am given a list of programs that can open that file.
This list keeps growing. For example, I once rented a Tesla and loaded the app, now that app keeps showing up in the list. I tried to delete the Tesla app, but obviously was not completely successful.
Other times, apps that can process that file do not show up, for instance ForScore shows up in some cases and not in others.
Is there anyway I can modify that list?
